# How does the Mac Web Dash board app work?

Tags: macos, browser, operating-system, webbrowser-control

Would like to understand how to build a tool like the mac os dash board widget (web clip). Am looking at trying to build it with webkit but not sure if thats the right way to go.

Some thoughts were to using webkit and some DOM to display only the viewport that a user requests.

While this works so well on mac os, am trying to build it on windows with .Net.

Answer (score 1):

Dashboard just uses webkit to display some HTML and JavaScript for the dynamic parts, but there are a couple of extensions. Apple have [developer documentation on Dashboard](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/Dashboard.html).